# I purchased a mobile home with my money out of a settlement I got

Tags: real-estate

What if it is just two friends who are no longer friends. I payed for my mobile home in full with my own money but put him on the title. Can I sell my share which is the full price to someone else?

Comment: What country... regulation vary. This is more apt on law.se ... if your friend is on title his consent is required.

Comment: Why would anyone pay the full price to own a 1/2 share with a stranger?

Comment: By putting your friend on the title you may have created a can of worms - I believe there is a presumption he is a part owner - and the assumption would not be that the friend was put on the title "for no reason".  It probably varies between jurisdictions, but there is probably a presumption that there were additional elements of the relationship which could entitle your friend to part (half?) the proceeds of ownership, absent documents to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

not enough data  for example does it show you or him or you and him on the title - "or" allows 100% ownership if either of you dies and "and" denotes 50% - you'd need to get a declaratory judgment that establishes his lack on contribution - and other factors of your original understanding  - sort it out in court if the facts stand in your favor - though the verbal understanding between you as to original intent of the purchase can get hairy -  plus, who is living in it -  if you hold and maintain control you could invoke UCC criteria that includes express (written) notice of you taking over control  then if you have control and pay the taxes (most states it is 7 years) you can claim adverse possession -   but sounds like you got yourself tied up in a mess that would cost you to resolve and maybe not to your advantage - 1st try to tie him into some written understand on your original agreement as a place to at least start